# How do I halve the width of a mesh while keeping it parallel to other edges (locking to an axis doesn't work)?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, edit-mode

[image]

I want to flatten this cube and keep it a rectangle, all edges parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You can change dimensions of a mesh by going to the Transform panel and input values directly into the fields under 'Scale'.

If you input 0.5 in the fields, assuming your mesh was already at Scale 1 for X, Y and Z, then it will be halved in all three dimensions while retaining it's current rectangular shape, it's position and alignment to other object and everything else. It will just become smaller.

You can also just change one or two of the dimensions and keep the other ones intact if you wish.

Comment: When i did that, they scaled to/from the point of origin(object center) and ruined the shape. how do i change the length of multiple edges that are equal by inputting a number?

Comment: I'm not too sure what exactly you want to do then. Changing the length of the edges will change the shape. What is your goal, what shape or size should the rectangle have when you're finished?

Comment: i want to stretch edges out while keeping them all parallel to each other. my object isn't a cube, and scaling isn't working, the object ceases to be parallel when i try

Answer (score 1):

I cant be sure the mesh is still aligned to the Local object axes from the picture, but if it is, switching  Transform Orientation to 'Local' in the header, and hitting <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> ( that is, tapping the dimension you're interested in, in Local space, *twice*) will scale the mesh along that axis.